# how to redirect to next page if all check box is unchecked

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, checkbox

i have html table see my html table below,if user click the image in the header it will not redirect it show the alert"please unchecked the all check box ", its only redirect if the user unchecked the all the check boxes .my problem was it now redirecting because the first td unchecked, it show alert if the first td checked,its only taking the first td i want to take all td .can any one guide be .see my code below

[image]

ajax

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#redirect").click(function() {

        var chkBox=$("#checkAddress");

         if (chkBox.attr('checked') != 'checked')
        {

     var clientid=document.getElementById("client").value;

        $.blockUI(

       { 

         message: '<h2>Please wait...</h2><img src="/image/loader.gif" />',
     timeout: 2000

       }); 


    $.ajax({
            type:"post",

        data:"clientid="+clientid,
        success:function(data){

                         window.location = '?action=clientpricenotification&clientid='+clientid+'';
                          $("#result").html(data);
                         $('.blockUI').hide();
        }
    }); 
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Please uncheck all the td");
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

html

```
  <th style="text-align:center ;width:200px">Route Update</th>
    <th style="text-align:center ;width:90px">By(Emp)</th>
    <th style="text-align:center ; width:32px"> <img id='redirect'  src="/image/Picture12.png" style="margin:0px;cursor:pointer;"> </th>

 echo ' <td style="width:200px" id="CPH_GridView1_Status1'.$rows['id'].'" class="route status1 '.$rows["id"].' "><input type="checkbox" style="margin:0 0 0 93px;" id="checkAddress" '.$checked_value.' name="checkAddress" '.$checked_value.' ></td>       

 <td id="CPH_GridView1_user" style="width:90px" class="edit user '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["user"].'</td>    

<td style="width:65px" class=" '.$rows["id"].'"></td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

This will listen to the `change()` event on all checkboxes so when it finds 0 checked, it will redirect.

```
 var $checkbox = $("input[type=checkbox]");
 var url = "http://.....";
 $checkbox.change(function(){
   if( $checkbox.is(":checked").length == 0 ) { window.location=url; }
 });
```

It should be enough for you to know how to apply it to your code.

Answer (score 0):

use document.getElementByTagname("input")..it will return the list of all input tags and you have to loop through the list to check every checkbox.RIGHT now you are only checking your first checkbox...

```
    var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0, max = allInputs.length; i < max; i++){
        if (allInputs[i].type === 'checkbox')
            if (allInputs[i].attr('checked') != 'checked'){
                   //your logic
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first you should define all input's id as :

```
id="checkAddress_{anythingunique}"
```

then

```
<script>
    var redir=1;
    $('input[id^="checkAddress_"]').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).attr('checked'))redire=0;
    });
    if(redir==1){
        //do your action
    }
</script>
```